# how to get the delay of ffmpeg?

Tags: networking, ffmpeg, compression, delay

I'm using ffmpeg to do some work on a network like this:

```
RtmpServer1 -- FfmpegServer -- RtmpServer2
```

I put a 6mins.mp4 on RtmpServer1(10.10.1.1) and play it on RtmpServer2(10.10.2.2) by this instruction:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://10.10.1.1:1935/play/6mins.mp4 -vcodec copy -c:v libx264 -f flv  rtmp://10.10.2.2:1935/live
```

I would like to know is there a way to test the length of the time ffmpeg use to decode, compress and encode?(the duration from ffmpeg server get the data to the ffmpeg server send it out)

I tried tcpdump to listen on the both two eth ports(one for get and one for send) of ffmpeg server. But I can't match RTMP packets by pairs("pairs" means the packets containing the same data, one "got" packet matches one "sent" packet). I'd also like to know if there's a way to match the RTMP packets by their content(data).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use tcpdump on both of the input and output eths and get when the rtmp streamings starts and ends. It is helpful in some way.